# How to apply orphans on table rows

Tags: html, css, pdf-generation

I need to display only 3 rows on the first page of pdf:

Example of table is here:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Medication:
            </td>
            <td>
                Formulation:
            </td>
            <td>
                Route:
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>
                Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This css doesn't give result:

```
@media print {
    table {
        tr {
            orphans: 3;      
        }            
    }
}
```

Does anyone have better solution how to display only 3 rows on one page of pdf?

Regards,
Srdjan

Comment: `@media print` will not affect a generated pdf unless you are doing it through print->Save as PDF. For pdf generation you will have its own templates and appropriate css will go into the start of it.